How do I group and sum data in a Pandas DataFrame?
I'm relatively new to Python, and I am trying to build a data analyzer for Formula 1. I am running into some trouble with manipulating DataFrames in Pandas.
Is there a way I can add together the points based on the year?
Note: The data is not real; it is an example for simplicity's sake.
points    year
1         1994
1         1994
2         1994
4         1994
10        1994
3         1995
3         1995
7         1995
8         1995
8         1995
2         1996
4         1996
6         1996
5         1996
5         1996

I have tried several different things but I cant seem to get my data to add together. I haven't been able to return anything I just keep getting errors.
I want the output to be in a new dataframe that shows
points    year
18         1994
29         1995
22         1996


Check this answer.

You can use the groupby method followed by sum:
result = df.groupby('year')['points'].sum().reset_index()


groupby('year'): Groups the data by the 'year' column.

['points'].sum(): Sums the 'points' for each group.

reset_index(): Resets the index to get a DataFrame instead of a Series.


